# Sequentally continuity and distributions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ open. We can a canonical topology on $C^\infty_{c}(\Omega)$ from seminorms
$$
\|f\|_{\alpha,K} := \|D^\alpha f\|_{L^\infty(K)}.
$$
I tried to prove that a linear functional $T$ is continuous if and only if is sequentially continuous. In fact, I have proved that this $C^\infty_{c}(\Omega)$ is complete, but it is not enough. Any idea?

Comment: This space is not complete. It is a metric space so sequential continuity is same as continuity.

Comment: Yes! You're right  $d(x,y) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2^{-n} \dfrac{\varrho_n(x- y)}{1 + \varrho_n(x-y)}$ is a distance, but I think that its complete... because de convergence over compact preserves the smoothness

Comment: With the topology you describe there are limits that are no compactly supported, ie Cauchy nets without limits in $C_c^\infty$. Also I assume you are looking at real differentiability, because there are no compactly supported complex differentiable functions.